# Printing out a string in any given coordinates c# console application

Tags: c#, string, printing, console

I want to create a program that prints out a string at any given coordinates with any foreground and background colors in a console application. For example, if the string contains "Hello!" i would like the "Hello!" text to be written out in the console, depending on where i put the coordinates. Here is my code:

```
class PrintString
{
    public int x, y; // Coordinates
    public string Text = "Hello!";
    ConsoleColor color;

    public PrintString(int x, int y, string Text)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = color;
        Console.SetCursorPostion(x, y);
        Console.Write(Text);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }

    public void Draw()
    {
        // Here I have no idea on how I should write the code for drawing the string?
    }
}
```

When i run this code i get: Error 4 `System.Console` does not contain a definition for `SetCursorPostion`

My question is, What am i missing for this to be as I wish?

Comment: What is the question? Are you having trouble to compile it or you don't know what are the contents of the `Draw` method should be?

Answer (score 0):

Well as the compiler states:

There is no method `SetCursorPostion`.

It's a typo:

Use `Console.SetCursorPosition(top,left);`

Comment: Yes,i changed that but I still dont get my string Im trying to figure out what the problem is but I have no idea...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? just output text in your command box? Why bother with `SetCursorPosition`? `Console.WriteLine()` will do just fine. What error are you running into ?